# How to stop driver's "TRANSFORM_FINAL" Error message from popping up in system console

Tags: python, animation, bones, constraints, drivers

There is a bone called CTRL_Head and it has Copy Location constraint.
I added a driver to this Copy Location constraint's mute state.  This driver simply checks scene's custom property and if this custom property is 1 this driver returns 0 if custom property is 0 driver returns 1, but I always get this error because of this driver, and this error seems not to cause anything bad but this error message itself is simply annoying because it fills up system console window.

```
find_node_operation: Failed for (TRANSFORM_FINAL, '')
add_relation(Target -> Driver) - Could not find op_from (OperationKey(type: TRANSFORM, component name: '', operation code: TRANSFORM_FINAL))
add_relation(Target -> Driver) - Failed, but op_to (OperationKey(type: PARAMETERS, component name: '', operation code: DRIVER, 'pose.bones["CTRL_Head"].constraints["Copy Location"].mute')) was ok
```

I don't know how to fix this error, so please tell me how to fix this.
I guess this error message pops up when "bpy.data.objects.pose.bones.constraints.mute" has a driver.

Comment: We'll need a lot more detail than this.  Can you add a blend file to your question that has an armature that shows the problem?  Is this happening in a script?  If so, please include it. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I can't upload blend file because it's so complicated and big. then this error is not general error.

Comment: make a copy of the file.  Delete everything but the armature that has the problem and any scripts. Is the problem still there?  Upload that file, if it is.

Comment: ok I will try to

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxg6m4zklanjm99/TEST_ARMATURE.blend?dl=0 this is the blend file, Just simply click "Update Dependencies" button in drivers editor please. you will see the error message in system console.